# SceneLayer not loading in ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-android

I am trying to load a simple scene layer into a simple scene using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android and it's not working. Here's a sample of my MainActivity.java file (based on the display-scene Android Runtime Sample):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private SceneView mSceneView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // create a scene and add a basemap to it
    ArcGISScene scene = new ArcGISScene();
    scene.setBasemap(Basemap.createImagery());

    ArcGISSceneLayer sceneLayer = new ArcGISSceneLayer("https://services9.arcgis.com/u0ju0TmDBL8ozsto/ArcGIS/rest/services/Meander_Dam_WSL2/SceneServer/layers/0");
    scene.getOperationalLayers().add(sceneLayer);

    // create SceneView from layout
    mSceneView = (SceneView) findViewById(R.id.sceneView);
    mSceneView.setScene(scene);

    ArcGISTiledElevationSource elevationSource = new ArcGISTiledElevationSource(
        getResources().getString(R.string.elevation_image_service));
    scene.getBaseSurface().getElevationSources().add(elevationSource);

    // add a camera and initial camera position
    Camera camera = new Camera(41.153, -80.7798, 300, -104, 0, 0); //Ohio dam
    mSceneView.setViewpointCamera(camera);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // pause SceneView
    mSceneView.pause();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // resume SceneView
    mSceneView.resume();
  }

  @Override protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // dispose SceneView
    mSceneView.dispose();
  }
}
```

The scene loads but my layer doesn't. I'm not having any problems loading this in the ArcGIS API for Javascript. What else do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after carefully comparing the scene layer metadata of the ESRI sample that was working and my layer that wasn't working. I had built my scene as a local scene in ArcGIS Pro and after it was published the spatial reference was set to Web Mercator (3857). The working examples all had spatial references of WGS84 (4326). I tried re-projecting things in my local scene but they were still getting published as with the Web Mercator (3857) spatial reference so I created a global scene with the same data and when I published it to AGOL I got the spatial reference, WGS84 (4326), that I needed. With the right spatial reference things loaded right up in the SDK scene. This article was helpful for figuring everything out: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/3d-gis/how-to-publish-scene-layers-in-arcgis-online/